# Convert Lat/Lon to Cartesian and back?

Tags: coordinate-system

Simple calculation that for some reason I'm getting very wrong:

```
def convert_to_vector(r, lat, long):
    x = r*math.cos(lat)*math.cos(long)
    y = r*math.cos(lat)*math.sin(long)
    z = r*math.sin(lat)
    return x, y, z


def convert_to_lat_long(x, y, z):
    r = math.sqrt(math.pow(x, 2)+math.pow(y, 2)+math.pow(z, 2))
    lat = math.acos(z/r)*180/math.pi
    long = math.atan2(x, y)*180/math.pi
    return lat, long


def convert_to_dec_degrees(deg, minutes, sec, direction):
    dec = deg + minutes/60 + sec/3600
    if direction == 'S' or direction == 'W':
        dec *= -1
    return dec

kansas_city = [convert_to_dec_degrees(39, 5, 59, 'N'), convert_to_dec_degrees(94, 34, 41, 'W')]
vector1 = convert_to_vector(1, kansas_city[0], kansas_city[1])
k_city_latlon = convert_to_lat_long(vector1[0], vector1[1], vector1[2])
print(kansas_city)
print([k_city_latlon[0], k_city_latlon[1]])
```

I can't tell which function is giving me the trouble, but I suspect its the conversion back to lat/lon.

The results print to console are:

```
[39.099722222222226, -94.57805555555555]
[9.7509365327902, 108.92341788716132]
```

Comment: `lat = math.acos(z/r)*180/math.pi` should be `lat = math.asin(z/r)*180/math.pi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting to degrees, but then in `convert_to_vector` you are treating those arguments as (implicitly) in radians, because `math.cos()` and `math.sin()` take [an argument in radians](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#trigonometric-functions).

You have the right idea in `convert_to_lat_long` where you do the `180/math.pi` part correctly. You just need to multiply the arguments by `math.pi/180` in your `convert_to_vector` function.

Comment: I should have read the docs closely. also, I was able to get the latitude back perfectly when adding your changes, and correcting for the fact that that theta = 90 - lat. Lon is still ~80 degrees off though(-174 v. -94)

Comment: x and y were switched in the arctan2 function. success!